# custom bootstrap nested columns alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I'm trying to align 3 columns underneath an embedded video. I want the edges of the columns to align with the edges of the video. I think I have to have the columns nested but I'm not sure. This is what I have so far, how do I customize this correctly? I need the columns responsive with the video.

https://jsfiddle.net/415w8ww8/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-wrapper center-block ">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6hoBp7Hk-A"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-offset-2">
        <h3 class="text-left">Record</h3>
        <p class="text-left">e 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into  </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h3 class="text-left">Integrate</h3>
        <p class="text-left">
          electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <h3 class="text-left">Share</h3>
        <p class="text-left">electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css[image]

```
@media all and ( min-width: 560px ) {
    .video-wrapper {
        width:797px;
        padding-bottom:444px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the nested `row` width to match the `video-wrapper` width.

See Snippet at Full Page.

```css
@media all and (min-width: 560px) {
  .video-wrapper {
    max-width: 797px;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
  .row.row-small {
    max-width: 797px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
}
/*BORDER IS FOR DEMO ONLY*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 video-wrapper center-block">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cx2lJIOTBjs?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="row row-small">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-left">Record</h3>
          <p class="text-left">e 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-left">Integrate</h3>
          <p class="text-left">
            electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-left">Share</h3>
          <p class="text-left">electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I include Normalize and Bootstrap:

[Live Preview in Codepen](http://codepen.io/AlejandroJSR7/full/yeepre/)

You must configure the height of the video:

This is posible with the next code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Video and Columns with bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <!--Main content container-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <iframe width="100%" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/b6hoBp7Hk-A" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Three columns -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Record</h3>
        <p>e 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Integrate</h3>
        <p>electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Hiya!</h3>
        <p>electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```